# UK Visitor Visa for my mother with my husband's sponsorship was denied once

Tags: uk, india, standard-visitor-visas

Me and my husband are sponsoring for my mother's visitor visa this time. Currently she is employed as a primary school teacher but she will be leaving her job i.e. retiring when coming to the UK. Her visa was refused once and now we're reapplying. I have a number of question in this regard:-

1. Last time I've shown her employment status as unemployed and planning to do so this time as well. But her bank statement has monthly deposit from her school like this "EBIZ TP
   CHRIST CHURCH HIGH SC". Could this be an issue?
2. Her monthly expense every month is not fixed. Sometimes it's 0, somtimes it's more than 10,000 INR. Should I give the average for 6 months?
3. One of the reason in the refusal letter was that "your spouse’s presence in your home country does not satisfy me that you intend to depart the UK at the end of your visit, nor that you seek entry for a purpose that is permitted under the visitor rules." Should I show my brother who's a currently a student as financial dependent on her?
4. Last time I didn't mention that I have due date in the month that she was supposed to visit. I stated her reason to visit is to "spend time with family". This time, I am planning to add my pregnancy point as well and her reason to visit will be "spend time with family and meet her future grandchild". Could this be an issue?
   [image]

Comment: What will your mother's income be after she retires? Does she have a pension? Is her husband employed and supporting her? Is your mother or her husband supporting your brother? Why is your mother's husband not coming with her?

Comment: No income after she retires as she's working in a local private school. No pension for her. My father, her husband is a farmer, so we can say self employed and he currently supports her partially.Only My father supports my brother, not my mum. My father is not coming with her as they live with my brother and elderly parents i.e. my grandparents and someone should be present to take care of them. Hope, I replied to every questions @DJClayworth

Comment: My question is closed but the one with which it says duplicate, doesn't have any reply to my specific  queries.

Comment: Have you read that answer carefully? It does give a lot of helpful information.

Comment: Yes, I've read that answer and all the linked ones as well. But I am looking for answers for my specific queries. I've tried to search for similar situations but couldn't find any, that's why I raised the question myself

Comment: @monicasharma IMHO the answers are: Q1 No, Q2 Yes, Q3 only if you can provide evidence. As a general rule, put yourself in the ECO’s shoes and the answer’s become clear

Comment: Since the duplicate didn't satisfy the OP, could we reopen?

Comment: @DJClayworth The question could be re-opened however IMHO the answer really amounts to “*tell the truth and explain anything unusual/not self-evident*”. Q3 might warrant a separate answer however since the OP says in a comment that her mother *does not* support her brother it’s not clear to me why the question is even being asked. So on balance I don’t think re-opening is worth it.

Comment: @Traveller There's more to it than that. For example explaining why the deposit name isn't a problem, and what other information she needs to provide (that I don't think is covered by the other answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot, DJClayworth and @Traveller. I had more concerns about Q1 and Q2. About Q3, it was more for getting third party perspective. IMO since my mum is unemployed, it doesn't make sense to show my brother as her financial dependent. However he's dependent on her how a son depends on her mum. But the refusal letter states that ECO wasn't satisfied with her intent to return from UK even though she's traveling alone and has family back home to take care of. I just want an opinion on how to show her intent to return back from UK, without pushing too hard and seeming desperate

Comment: @monicasharma I don’t see Q1 or Q2 as a problem - for Q1 just explain what the monthly deposit from the school relates to, and for Q2 the ‘average’ figure with an explanation should be fine. This may not be what you want to hear for Q3 but IMHO if UKVI did not consider having a spouse to return to as a compelling reason to leave the UK, I’m not sure adding a non-financially dependent student son back home as well will carry any more weight.

Comment: @Traveller Thanks a ton for your helpful replies. I have added another Q4,  would you mind to give your POV on that. TIA.

Comment: @monicasharma she may well be travelling alone to get to the UK, but she would not be alone once she arrived - she would be with you and your husband. Considering that it would not be all that unusual for a mother to move in and live with her daughter and son-in-law, she needs to make the ECO feel that, on the balance of probabilities, doing just that is not her intention. Since she has no income or pension after retirement, trying to name your brother as a dependent is unlikely to be believed.

Comment: Imo, although giving the details of your pregnancy & due date to someone you don't know might feel uncomfortable, I think it's likely to improve the chances of an approval (assuming you also address the other issues like her monthly spending discrepancies), since a mother visiting her pregnant daughter is a perfectly normal & expected thing.

Comment: Voted to re-open in view of the lengthy comments and addition of Q4 to the original question. Was the refusal recent? If so, the ECO might wonder why you didn’t state the pregnancy as the reason for the visit in that application

Comment: @Traveller, yes the refusal was recent, in the first week of August. I didn't mention the pregnancy in the last application, as brhans mentioned, you don't really broadcast about the pregnancy, but desperate times.

Comment: @monicasharma IMHO it would have been better to tell the truth first time, rather than create a situation where it might seem that the pregnancy was the real reason for the visit all along but wasn’t stated as such first time round. However, IMHO the *reason* for the visit is not the main problem. The key issue to resolve is overcoming the *lack of ties to home* vs *ties to family in UK* hurdle. It would be much better, for example, if your mother was not planning to retire before her proposed visit to the UK.

Answer (score 7):

There are three distinct issues raised in the rejection letter:

A) Your mother's financial situation is somewhat unclear, with the focus being on her expenses. Entering the running monthly average for her expenses into the box makes sense, but you'll also need to add some explanation explaining her situation and how the numbers you've entered into the form are related to the evidence. Because the situation is unclear, the ECO has doubts regarding your mother's honesty.

B) Your husband said that he'd pay £3000 for your mother's visit, but there was no evidence that your husband has £3000 to spare. This again raises an honesty problem, in addition to the issue that if there isn't enough money to support your mom during her stay, she may end up working, which she musn't.

C) What reason does your mother have to go home? The ECO acknowledges that returning to her husband is a reason, but they aren't convinced that it is enough of a reason. You are probably facing a challenging baseline assumption based on her country of citizenship and financial situation here, which may be hard to overcome. Being unemployed certainly doesn't help. Claiming that she has to financially support her college-age son also won't help: This doesn't require her to be in India, and she will be unemployed anyway. Instead, this might make matters worse as it would be a reason for her to work illegally in the UK.

I don't think that the "seek entry for a purpose that"-part is at all connected to "visiting family" being an insufficient reason. Instead, this just follows from the financial issues and subsequent potential incentive to work illegally. Thus, I don't think that mentioning your pregnancy would have much of an impact. If you do mention it, be careful not to give the idea that your mother would "work" for you as a babysitter, "maid", etc.

Ultimately, you definitely have to fix issues A) and B) for the reapplication, otherwise it's pointless to even try. There probably isn't much to can do about C) directly, but hopefully fixing A) and B) will tilt the overall impression enough in your mom's favour that she can visit.